# How can I fill the variables from file?

Tags: bash

How can I fill the variables from file?

In `/root/file` I have 4 lines (number and text)

```
478
144
text
0
```

How can I set the values of four variables, one value from each line of the file?

The desired result:

```
ABC="478"
DEF="144"
GHI="text"
JKL="0"
```

Comment: Where did `ABC`, `DEF`, etc. come from?!

Comment: are the number of lines in your file fixed?

Comment: If number of lines are static, you can use awk like this: `ABC=$(awk 'NR==1' /root/file)`

Answer (score 4):

Say the file is called `file.txt`. Just read each line into the desired variable, one at a time, using a compound command.

```
{ IFS= read -r ABC; IFS= read -r DEF; IFS= read -r GHI; IFS= read -r JKL; } < file.txt
```

If you know that `file.txt` is "simple", that is, you don't care about leading or trailing whitespace on the lines or backslash-escaped line continuations, you can drop the `IFS=` and `-r` clutter and just use

```
{ read ABC; read DEF; read GHI; read JKL; } < file.txt
```

---

We use the compound command `{ ... }` to share the input from `file.txt` among all the reads; without it, using something like

```
read ABC < file.txt
read DEF < file.txt
read GHI < file.txt
read JKL < file.txt
```

each `read` would read from the beginning of the file, resulting in the first line of the file being assigned four times.

Comment: wow that is pretty cool.  it works but I dont understand what read does.  thnx!

Comment: `read` simply reads a single line from its standard input and assigns it to the variable named by its argument. In this case, we wrap the four `read`s in a compound command so that they share a single input stream from the file; the first `read` sees the first line, the second `read` the second line, etc.